# Probability Independence and Boolean Events

Tags: probability, independence

A and B are two Boolean events that are independent of each other. P(A) = 0.3 and P(B) = 0.6.
Compute the following three quantities:

P (A and B).

P (A or B).

P (A => B).

Note that (A => B) is a Boolean expression. You are asked to compute the probability that (A => B) evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use the product rule for the probability of the intersection of independent events.

(2) Use the additive rule for the probability of the union of *non* disjoint events.

(3) Use Implication Equivalence to express the Boolean statement in Distributive Normal Form, then evaluate the probability as above.